# How to monitor a growing log file for specific string and print the line to terminal in realtime?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, monitor, log

For example. I have `nohup.out.log` file which is growing over time. I want to monitor this file and check if the string `test error` occurs in this file and print the corresponding lines to terminal or another file such as `error.log` in real-time.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the directory that has `nohup.out.log` and do...

```
/usr/bin/tail -f nohup.out.log | grep "test error" > error.log
```

and it will wait for "test error" to occur.

See [man tail](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html) for more options.

Comment: That's what I need. Thanks!

Comment: Might worth noting as well that `-F` will keep trying to open a file if it is inaccessible as opposed to `-f`.

Answer (score 1):

[`lnav`](https://lnav.org/features) is a really good logfile explorer for the terminal that features filtering, syntax highlighting etc.

If you have the `universe` repo enabled, it can be installed with:

```
sudo apt install lnav
```

To use it with a specific logfile, run:

```
lnav /path/to/nohup.out.log
```

To set up a filter, press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>i</kbd>. Then type the string `test error` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Now only log lines with this string is shown.

Comment: A useful tool, though I have no root user. Thanks.